# ObjectMapper Terminates Program

Tags: java, jackson

When I run the below code the output is only "Before". It never reaches "After".
What's strange is that no error is thrown.

The below code is inside an object which is instantiated in a Junit test. Some of the code called before this snippit is reached interacts with Apollo MQ. What's really strange is that this works the first time when the Apollo MQ service is started. The 2nd time on ward fails to reach "After". Restarting Apollo MQ will fix this issue.

```
`import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
log.info("Before");
Container c = mapper.readValue("{\"id\":\"abc123\"}", Container.class);
log.info("After");
...
public class Container
{
    String id;
}`
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Something is throwing an exception somewhere? Have you tried stepping through this in the debugger to see what it does?

Comment: It throws no exceptions and when I use the debugger it ends. When I go to Container c = mapper.readValue("{\"id\":\"abc123\"}", Container.class); and step into it the program ends.